# How to compensate for incomplete date/time info in filename

Tags: exiftool

For some reason I'm getting

> no writeable tags

when I run the standard `exiftool "-alldates<$filename` command. I've kicked around and my best guess is that it has to do with the date format in the filename.

I've got files named with the format `YYYY_MM_DD_?` where I'm not... entirely sure what that `?` is supposed to be. Sometimes it's one character, sometimes two (thanks a lot, export tool).

Am I on the right track? If so, how can I adjust my command to compensate? If not, can anyone diagnose the problem and provide a suggestion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to copy a time stamp from the filename, you must have at least 14 numbers in order to cover the date (YYYYMMDD) and the time (HHmmSS) in this case.  Exiftool isn't picky when doing this operation about where the numbers are, but there needs to be 14.  In cases where you don't actually know the time, you can do something like `"-alldates<$filename 000000` in order to add a 00:00:00 time to the timestamp.  See [exiftool FAQ #5](https://exiftool.org/faq.html#Q5) for more details on copying dates from filename.

Comment: Thanks! That's one piece of the puzzle solved. I have follow up questions, but I'll open a new question ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57169580/troubleshooting-no-writeable-tags-set-error ) to ask since it's a little outside the scope of this one.

Comment: Feel free to come over to the [exiftool forums](http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/index.php) for extra help.  It's a bit easier to communicate and show examples in a forum setting, IMO.